# Provide a /24 subnet for a bridged VirtualBox guest

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge, vlan

On a host running VirtualBox, I have a bridged virtual machine requiring more than just one IP address as well as several virtual network devices collected in a VLAN.

Unfortunately, VirtualBox cuts off every traffic which is not sent by or to the actual main virtual NIC of the guest machine.

The host's IP: `10.42.42.10/32`

The bridged guest's IP: `10.42.42.100/24`

The virtual NIC's IPs *inside* the virtual machine: `10.42.42.105/32`, `10.42.42.106/32` ...

*(They are dynamically generated as I occasionally require some more virtual NICs. That's why they are not created as a NIC in VirtualBox but as a VLAN inside the VM)*

Unfortunately, every traffic sent to `105`, `106` gets dropped by the host. They are even not able to get an IP address assigned from the router on `10.42.42.1` nor to ping the guest's main NIC's IP.

Is there any way to make VirtualBox route an IP subnet to a virtual machine? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to have a machine with two NICs on the same network?  That doesn't really make sense and is bound to cause problems.

Comment: Well, I have about 10~15 virtual NICs inside the VM. They are all dynamically generated. That's why they are not directly attached to the host but bundled inside a VLAN.

Comment: The host network being `/32` doesn't make sense, it should be `/24` like the rest of the network. Also, VLAN is a router concept, what do you mean by it? Which operating systems are host and guest?

Comment: The host runs VirtualBox on Arch Linux Kernel 5.9 and the Guest runs Proxmox VE Kernel 5.4. Hence, I have a virtualization environment inside a virtual machine. Inside Proxmox, the created containers and VMs should be bridged to the host's network `192.168.0.1/24`. It is not the bridge which should have the `/32` but the host's unique IP. And that's exactly what's causing my issues.